# How to detect receipt of a 0-length UDP datagram

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I was considering writing/implementing a UDP-based protocol that would use a zero-length datagram as a 'hello' message.  And while I don't expect to have a problem sending a zero-length datagram, I'm not certain I can receive one.

[recvfrom](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) returns the number of bytes read, but 0 is reserved for an orderly shutdown.

[read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) returns number of bytes read, but 0 is reserved for EOF.

[select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) "will be watched to see if characters become available for reading".

How would one detect the receipt of a zero-length datagram?

Comment: Maybe design your protocol so it doesn't require 0-length UDP packets? Even if this isn't an issue for you on the OS you're using today, it seems like an edge case that might behave differently on a different OS platform. There's essentially no addiational overhead for sending a UDP packet with 1 byte of data instead of 0, so why not eliminate the issue if you can?

Comment: I have eliminated the issue by modifying the protocol, so that this isn't necessary.  But I'm still curious as to whether or not it can be done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When calling `recvfrom` on a TCP Socket, you will receive a zero byte read if a FIN packet has been received (an orderly shutdown). UDP has no concept of orderly shutdowns, and no data is transmitted from the sender to receiver to indicate a socket being closed. The protocol is completely stateless and every datagram received is independent from the receiver's point of view. As such, I am not aware of any scenerios in which a zero byte return code from recvfrom on a UDP socket would be caused by anything other than a zero length datagram being received.

Comment: True, but because 0 is reserved for a special situation, even if it doesn't make sense for UDP, I believe that recvfrom would continue to block, and not return 0 in that situation.

Comment: Yes, `recvfrom()` would return 0 if it receives a 0-length packet (at least on Windows).  MSDN's documentation says as much: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120.aspx) "For UDP if the packet received contains no data (empty), the return value from the recvfrom function function is zero."

Comment: Apparently it's possible with POSIX as well.  I only *thought* I changed the protocol to avoid the 0-length packet, but didn't actually change it.  And then I wondered why recvfrom kept returning 0...

Comment: On Linux as well recvfrom() returns 0 if it receives a zero-length UDP datagram.

Comment: What you're saying is true, but there can be reliable, sequenced, message-oriented protocols. How would a reliable, sequenced, message-oriented protocol which allows zero-length messages indicate "no more messages?" The ambiguity is real!

Answer (score 1):

For udp, a normal call to `recvfrom` will return 0 when receiving a udp packet with 0 length payload (see [Under Linux, can recv ever return 0 on UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505892/under-linux-can-recv-ever-return-0-on-udp)).

You can test this by doing a simple sendto/recvfrom test:

```
    const int howManyBytesToSend = 0;
    if(sendto(sock, buf, howManyBytesToSend, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, addrlen) < 0)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if((recv_len = recvfrom(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

---

The documentation you are quoting is from the man page for recvfrom: "returns the number of bytes read, but 0 is reserved for an orderly shutdown". That statement applies only to TCP.