# Why would you send a UDP packet with no payload?

Tags: udp

It seems that a UDP packet can be sent without a payload.

The only thing I can think of that doesn't need a payload is for NAT hole punching.
What else could this be used for?

This relates to my previous question [Under Linux, can recv ever return 0 on UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505892/under-linux-can-recv-ever-return-0-on-udp)

I suppose more to the point is that if it's been specified as part of some standard, then it's been thought to be useful somewhere right?

Comment: Not sure this is a real question - maybe you should ask the sender of the packet :-)

Comment: It's a real question and relates to my previous question.  It's allowed so why would you do this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505892/under-linux-can-recv-ever-return-0-on-udp

Comment: and people reading this question know nothing of your previous question - so in itself this is not helpful - hey maybe I just felt like sending an empty UDP message because I had nothing else to do - the point of my comment is how will this help someone in 6 month time

Comment: Good edits to the question - it is more useful now - Grrr cannot remove my close vote

Comment: maybe take off the vote to close, I think it's a pretty clear and valid question now

Comment: I want too - I do not see the option too - any pointers on how?

Comment: @Matt - I apologize for the close vote :-( sorry - want to remove it

Comment: No worries, good thing it takes more than 1 vote to close.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Anything! The UDP packet isn't empty -- it comes with the sender's identity. Therefore, such a packet could be used as a primitive kind of signal: maybe a hello, a goodbye, or a keep-alive.

With interfaces like `sendmsg`, an empty packet might be used in order to send auxiliary data, like a `cmsg` structure (which can be used for things like transferring file descriptors between two processes on Linux).

EDIT: One more use: NAT traversal algorithms such as [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) or UDP hole punching.

Comment: How about adding Heartbeats, routing tests, and what is that horrible protocol that tries to work out if you are NAT'ed or not

Comment: UDP hole punching? Yeah, like I said, tons of applications.

Comment: Something my PS3 does - the protocol has a name - cannot remember what it is called

Comment: Ok, this is starting to make some sense as to why it could be useful.

Comment: Oh and with multicast it could keep group subscriptions active

Comment: Ok, this statement a bit odd.  "an empty packet might be used in order to send auxiliary data". How could an empty packet send auxiliary data without actually sending auxiliary data?

Comment: @Matt there is data in the UDP header which is available to the app which the sender did not explicitly supply ie the source IP address

Comment: It's not in the UDP header; `cmsg` lives in a kind of "out of band" channel which happens to arrive with the UDP packet. See [`man 2 sendmsg`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/sendmsg/) for more information.

Comment: See also http://www.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node121.html for some examples of `sendmsg`-based magic tricks.

Comment: @nneonneo Should have referenced http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure

Comment: Well, the UDP header has the port, and the IP header has the IP address. So, technically, showing just the UDP doesn't tell the full story. (And yes, I know it might not be UDP/IP; point is that the information in the packet is not just from the UDP header, but maybe from the encapsulating header too).

Comment: Sorry empty payload, not packet.

Comment: @nneonneo It is in the UDP header and the IP header. There is no mysterious 'out of band channel that happens to arrive with the UDP packet'. This is computing, not magic.

Comment: @EJP: I was talking about `cmsg` control messages, auxiliary data for packets. These messages *are* sent out of band. See `man 2 sendmsg`. If you aren't familiar with them, they can seem like magic (you can *give a copy of your file descriptors to another process* for example, or determine the UID/GID of the process on the other end of the socket using these messages). See the link I posted.

Comment: I see the confusion. The message discussing `cmsg` was meant to be @Matt, not @AdrianCornish.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of "why would a protocol do this": the old Daytime protocol just uses the arrival of a UDP packet to send back a reply packet. Similarly, it replies with time value as soon as a TCP connection happens regardless of any actual data that the TCP connection contains.

Answer (score 0):

a UDP packet without payload may be sent to detect if a UDP port is closed. if closed, an ICMP-unreach is replied.