# Improving this udp client design

Tags: c++, c++17, udp, boost-asio

I have programmed a very simple `udp` client using `boost::asio`.

Knowing that `udp` is connectionless, I wonder if is there any better way to improve this design while fullfiling with these two constraints:

1. This code will be hosted as a class in a library (windows `dll`), so several instances of this client (each containing a socket) can be created.
2. By requirement, the computer will have several network cards, so it's a strong requiriment allowing to select the client IP, as well as its port.
3. Solution must compile under c++17.

As being a dll, I have used the same `io_context` service as a global variable for all the clients, passing a reference to it when creating each client, but this isn't a must but my own election, so if any better dessign is propossed it will be welcome.

For improving, I mean if is possible to use only one socket for send and for to received together with a list of entry endpoints peers, without the need to bind to one and only one endpoint. Maybe I am being naivy and there isn't any way of doing this, maybe neither the need to save resources when only a few hundreds of them might be used at a time (from 100 to 200), but having little experience with `udp` I would like to learn more about this subject.

```
#define _SILENCE_CXX17_ALLOCATOR_VOID_DEPRECATION_WARNING
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace udpsocket
{

    using boost::asio::ip::udp;
    using Id = udp::endpoint;
    using Data = std::vector<unsigned char>;
    using Buffer = std::array<unsigned char, 512>;

    // NOTE: Client version with external io_context (one for all sockets/websockets in application)
    class client
    {
    public:
        client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context) : socket{ io_context } {}

        bool is_open() { return socket.is_open(); }

        void open(const std::string& host, unsigned short port)
        {
            if (socket.is_open()) return;

            udp::endpoint endpoint{ boost::asio::ip::make_address_v4(host), port };// 0 for ephemeral port
            socket.open(endpoint.protocol());
            socket.set_option(udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
            socket.bind(endpoint);
            receive();
        }

        void resolve(const std::string& host, const std::string& port)
        {
#if BOOST_VERSION < 107000
            udp::resolver resolver{ socket.get_io_context() };
#else
            udp::resolver resolver{ socket.get_executor() };
#endif

            endpoint = *resolver.resolve(udp::v4(), host, port);
        }

        void send(const unsigned char* data, size_t bytes)
        {
            if (socket.is_open())
                socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, bytes), endpoint);// auto length =
        }

        void receive()
        {
            udp::endpoint entry_endpoint;
            socket.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), entry_endpoint, [this](boost::system::error_code error, size_t bytes) {
                if (!error && bytes)
                    datagrams.emplace_back(buffer.data(), buffer.data() + bytes);

                receive();
            });
        }

        std::list<Data> received()
        {
            return std::exchange(datagrams, {});
        }

    private:
        udp::socket     socket;
        udp::endpoint   endpoint;
        Buffer          buffer;
        std::list<Data> datagrams;
    };

}//namespace udpsocket

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    udpsocket::client client1(io_context);
    udpsocket::client client2(io_context);
    udpsocket::client client3(io_context);

    client1.open("127.0.0.1", 1000);
    client2.open("127.0.0.1", 1001);
    client3.open("127.0.0.1", 1002);

    client1.resolve("127.0.0.1", "50000");
    client2.resolve("127.0.0.1", "50001");
    client3.resolve("127.0.0.1", "50002");

    auto clients = std::array{ std::ref(client1), std::ref(client2), std::ref(client3) };
    while (true) {
        auto index{ std::rand() % clients.size() };
        auto msg = "I am client number " + std::to_string(index + 1);
        clients[index].get().send(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(msg.c_str()), msg.size());

        io_context.poll();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }

}
```

NOTE: In order to provide a minimum and OS neutral source code, I haven't used a dll but a normal console exe, but the spirit of the question is the same regardless the architecture.

Comment: Do you have a plan for: (1) out-of-order UDP packets; (2) split UDP packets; (3) both (1) + (2); and (4) missing UDP packets ?

Comment: @Richard Critten Now I have had time to understand what you really meant. All those issues you told about are covered at application level, using a message protocol with headers and trails containing sequence numbers, time stamping and CRC codes. Not included in example source code to avoid obscuring the real question. Thank you for your comment, very appreciated.

Comment: "I mean if is possible to use only one socket for send and for to received together with a list of entry endpoints peers" - udp being connection less, yes. But it's unclear what requirement you have ("list of endpoint peers"). I hope my answer accidentally addresses this issue by removing/deprecating the stateful approach in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

> As being a dll, I have used the same io_context service as a global variable for all the clients, passing a reference to it when creating each client, but this isn't a must but my own election, so if any better dessign is propossed it will be welcome.

In principle don't tie your users down. Take an executor. That way users can use `asio::io_context`, `asio::thread_pool`, a strand on some other executor or even `system_executor{}`.

`receive` is really `receive_loop` and must not be public (it's invalid for people to call it).

The `receive_loop` should probably terminate on errors.

There should probably be rate limiting to avoid `datagrams` to grow without limit.

You lose source information from datagrams. This might be on purpose, but it seems odd when you expect datagrams from disparate sources.

You have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the `async_receive_from` takes a reference to the local variable `entry_endpoint`.

The Buffer hardcodes a size limit much lower than general UDP packet limit. This seems arbitrary. Again, don't tie your users down. https://superuser.com/questions/1697793/the-maximum-length-of-a-datagram-packet-is-65-536-or-65-535/1697822#1697822

`Buffer` has excessive scope. It can be a private member of `client`.

`Id` is declared but not used (probably a good thing though).

You resolve an endpoint but discards all but the first result. This may or not be safe depending on your application domain.

`send` silently ignores the command if the socket is not connected. This may lead to surprised users.

`send` arbitrarily requires `unsigned char*`. You already realize how user-friendly that is:

```
c.send(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(msg.c_str()), msg.size());
```

In C++20 you'd use `std::span` (optionally with `std::as_bytes`). Until then, consider Boost's.

You are explicitly discarding empty datagrams. This may, again, be valid, but for a general purpose client will lead to surprises. [Why would you send a UDP packet with no payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506227/why-would-you-send-a-udp-packet-with-no-payload)

You used `std::list` for the datagrams. Presumably that's because you like the reference/iterator stability. In most cases prefer `std::vector`. If you use `std::deque` you will *still* enjoy reference/iterator stability as long as you insert/remove only from the front/back.

Using `rand() % N` invites bias. Instead use `std::sample`. In c++ you could even use `std::ranges::sample` which is a lot more convenient to write.

Your interface is mixed between synchronous and asynchronous. While I think it's correct that `send_to` will immediately hand off to the kernel, it seems more hygienic to choose an approach. Again, minimizing surprises.

Depending on where you call members they can case data races on both the destination endpoint and entry_endpoint. You can also cause UB by causing overlapping reads.

Fixing this gets complicated fast, because e.g. to fix the strand synchronization of `send`, you'd need to post the actual send to the strand, which suddenly puts a lifetime requirement on `data`:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> void send(span<T, N> data) { // throws if not open
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && std::is_standard_layout_v<T>);

    post(socket.get_executor(),
         std::packaged_task{[this, data] { socket.send_to(asio::buffer(data), destination); }})
        .get();
}
```

At this time, even your sample use (in `main`) would **not** correctly be guarding those lifetimes. Instead I'd go the other way and pass the message by value, so you can fix both the serialization **and** the non-overlapping requirements in one go.

It is possible to call `send` without any `resolve`. It's unclear what will happen.

Getting the received datagrams is tricky: to get it synchronizing correctly you might use a future:

```
auto received() {
    return asio::dispatch(socket.get_executor(),
                          std::packaged_task{[this] { return std::exchange(datagrams, {}); }})
        .get();
}
```

Alternatively, consider atomic exchange, e.g. with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2

Using `io_context.poll()` is an antipattern, especially with low frequency in a - supposedly - high throughput application?

The biggest question I have here is mostly what the example should demonstrate. It never exercises `received` so it's unclear to me what the expected output would be.

---

### My $0.02

With all that said, I'd arrive at the following minimal change. I'm not saying this is a good design (see above for some questions) but it does resolve most of the concrete issues with the original code.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa7569e76e72b8be)**

```
#include <array>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

namespace udpsocket {
    using boost::asio::ip::udp;
    using boost::system::error_code;
    using Data = std::vector<unsigned char>;
    struct Datagram {
        Data          payload;
        udp::endpoint endpoint;
    };

    static udp::endpoint resolve(std::string const& host, std::string const& port) {
        udp::resolver resolver{asio::system_executor{}};
        return *resolver.resolve(udp::v4(), host, port);
    }

    // NOTE: Client version with external io_context (one for all sockets/websockets in application)
    class client {
      public:
        client(asio::any_io_executor ex, std::string const& host, uint16_t port) : socket{ex} {
            udp::endpoint endpoint{asio::ip::make_address_v4(host), port}; // 0 for ephemeral port
            socket.open(endpoint.protocol());
            socket.set_option(udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
            socket.bind(endpoint);

            receive_loop();
        }

        void send(Datagram dg) {
            asio::dispatch(socket.get_executor(), [this, dg = std::move(dg)]() mutable {
                outbox_.push_back(std::move(dg));
                if (outbox_.size() == 1)
                    write_loop();
            });
        }

        void send(Data data, udp::endpoint target) {
            return send(Datagram{std::move(data), std::move(target)});
        }

        [[deprecated("prefer the stateless overload of send taking a Datagram")]]
        void resolve_target(std::string const& host, std::string const& port) {
            asio::dispatch(socket.get_executor(), [=] {
                udp::resolver resolver{socket.get_executor()};
                target = *resolver.resolve(udp::v4(), host, port);
            });
        }

        [[deprecated("prefer the stateless overload of send taking a Datagram")]]
        void send(Data data) {
            return send(Datagram{std::move(data), target});
        }

        auto received() {
            return asio::dispatch(socket.get_executor(),
                                  std::packaged_task{[this] { return std::exchange(datagrams, {}); }})
                .get();
        }

      private:
        // all private member functions assume invocation on strand
        void write_loop() {
            if (outbox_.empty())
                return;
            auto& dg = outbox_.front();
            socket.async_send_to(asio::buffer(dg.payload), dg.endpoint, [this](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                if (!ec) {
                    outbox_.pop_front();
                    write_loop();
                } // else: TODO handle error?
            });
        }

        void receive_loop() {
            incoming.payload.resize(65507);
            incoming.endpoint = {};
            socket.async_receive_from(asio::buffer(incoming.payload), incoming.endpoint,
                                      [this](error_code error, size_t bytes) {
                                          if (!error) {
                                              incoming.payload.resize(bytes);
                                              datagrams.push_back(std::move(incoming));
                                              receive_loop();
                                          } // else: TODO handle error?
                                      });
        }

        udp::socket          socket;
        udp::endpoint        target; // deprecated
        Datagram             incoming;
        std::deque<Datagram> datagrams;
        std::deque<Datagram> outbox_;
    };

} // namespace udpsocket

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    asio::thread_pool io_context;

    std::array clients{
        udpsocket::client{make_strand(io_context), "127.0.0.1", 11000},
        udpsocket::client{make_strand(io_context), "127.0.0.1", 11001},
        udpsocket::client{make_strand(io_context), "127.0.0.1", 11002},
    };

    std::array targets{
        udpsocket::resolve("127.0.0.1", "50000"),
        udpsocket::resolve("127.0.0.1", "50001"),
        udpsocket::resolve("127.0.0.1", "50002"),
    };

    auto choose = [](auto& from) -> auto& {
        static std::mt19937 prng{std::random_device{}()};
        return from.at(std::uniform_int_distribution(0ul, size(from) - 1)(prng));
    };

    while (true) {
        auto&       c   = choose(clients);
        std::string msg = "I am client number " + std::to_string(&c - clients.begin()) + "\n";
        auto        b = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(msg.data()), e = b + msg.size();
        c.send(udpsocket::Data(b, e), choose(targets));

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}
```

With a local demo:

[image]